# Klein's absolute invariant and eta-quotients

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Could anyone please provide a reference for $(13)$, $(14)$, $(17)$, $(18)$, $(21)$, $(22)$, which are stated on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinsAbsoluteInvariant.html) without proper citation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not as explicit as I would like, but Weber's 1908 *Lehrbuch der Algebra*, volume III, chapter 7, has background on the subject.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look. I contacted MathWorld Team yesterday and asked them to provide a reference.

Comment: @ccorn I do not speak German, so I am not entirely sure what is happening in Chapter 7. Could you please point out where Weber states the identities from MathWorld?

Comment: @ccorn I managed to prove $(13)$, $(14)$. However, I have no clue how to prove $(17)$, $(18)$, $(21)$, $(22)$.

Comment: Modular equations are best won with a systematic approach, which is what Weber presents in Vol. III, ch. 7. Without that, but with enough patience, you can at least check consistency of (21)...(24) with formulae about the [RRCF](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rogers-RamanujanContinuedFraction.html). Much can be said about the eta quotients in (17)...(20), but I am not aware of catchy names for them. In any case, I recommend that you study Dedekind's $\eta$ a bit because you can express all other functions with it.

Comment: Another good read is Borwein & Borwein's *Pi and the AGM*, Wiley 1987. Chapters 4 and 5 treat modular equations in a way that gets you started almost immediately. You are then free to consult further references for generalizations.

Comment: Thank you. I have this book, so I will have a look.